# OpenShift deploy from Dockerfile referencing image in internal registry

Tags: docker, openshift

We have successfully deployed to OpenShift from a Dockerfile and can verify that is exists via:

```
oc get is -n my-project
my-image-a image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000/my-project/my-image-a
```

We would like to reference this from another Dockerfile like:

```
FROM my-image-a
```

This results in:

```
Pulling image my-image- ...
Warning: Pull failed, retrying in 5s ...
Warning: Pull failed, retrying in 5s ...
Warning: Pull failed, retrying in 5s ...
error: build error: failed to pull image: After retrying 2 times, Pull image still failed due to 
error: errors:
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
unauthorized: authentication required
```

How do we authenticate? We have no issue pushing the image, but pulling it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

you can authenticate using this command:

```
docker login -u $(oc whoami) -p $(oc whoami -t) registry-openshift-image-registry.apps.<your-cluster-host>
```